# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException in the json parsing

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

please help me in this as I am new to android.
while parsing the json, I am retreiving the values of paricular Json Object when selected a partcular Json object.

Answer (score 1):

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

This error shows you are using json parsing in the main thread.

You need to use `AsynkTask`.

Basically this error tells us doing to much of work on the onCreate method. So you must use asynkTask for avoiding this.